# Java Annotations simple error

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I am newbie at Java EE and I have a simple problem.
I created a project using Maven plugin's default directory structure and I want to annotate a class as @Loggable, but I get a

> Loggable cannot be resolved to a type

error. Any annotation I want to use can't be resolved to a type. What's the problem? I suspect that it has to do with dependency or build path issues but I can seem to get it working.

Comment: Did the loggable annotation class library in the classpath ? If it's not there then you may face this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a list of dependencies in the pom.xml file of your maven project. Make sure the jar that has `Loggable` is listed as a dependency.

Read [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) how to do it.

Your `import java.lang.annotation.*;` will not help as `Loggable` is not in that namespace.

Maybe you should write this Annotation on your own. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) to learn more.

Comment: I had to write the annotation on my own. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have to `import` annotation classes just like anything else. Use an IDE such as Eclipse; it will handle and many similar tasks for you automatically.

Comment: I do, and I already have imported `import java.lang.annotation.*;` but still no resolve.

Comment: There is no Loggable annotation in java.lang.annotation.

Comment: @GeorgeD There are dozens of `Loggable`s out there. Which framework are you trying to use.